# avoiding user's fraud using inspect element

Tags: html, css

how to avoid users eliminating css using inspect element?
let's say I have a form where if all inputs are not filled in then the submit button has the disabled style, but if you inspect the element and remove the CSS the user can submit even though all the form is not filled in, is there any insight for me?

Comment: Maintain the state of the form elements in the memory using a variable that cannot be accessed from outside. On submit, validate using the variable. Additionally, use server side validation.

Comment: Never trust *any* input you don't have control over and validate all the input you receive on the server-side before even thinking about processing it

Comment: What may shock you even more: anyone can send any arbitrary HTTP request straight to your server, not even using your web frontend at all. Because that’s all it is in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. HTML, CSS and Javascript are executed at the client side. He can do what he wants if he knows how.

It is very important to validate the form on server side too because the user can not access the server.

Answer (score -3):

To be honest no, you can't avoid user to access inspect element, but you can prevent user to press :

1. Right Click
2. F12
3. Ctrl + Shift + I
4. Ctrl + Shift + J
5. Ctrl + U

```js
//keys
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (event.keyCode == 123) {
    return false;
  }
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'I'.charCodeAt(0)) {
    return false;
  }
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'J'.charCodeAt(0)) {
    return false;
  }
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'U'.charCodeAt(0)) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
//right-click
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
```

Source: [andrewstutorials.blogspot.com](https://andrewstutorials.blogspot.com/2014/03/disable-ways-to-open-inspect-element-in.html)

Comment: You should never disable the browser's  default behaviors. This will just frustrate the end-users (and can be circumvented anyways)